# PHP check in Array from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to search in a array from mysql if one dates from a columns is the current date. For exemple i have this dates in array:

```
2013-09-03,2013-09-04,2013-09-06,2013-09-05,2013-09-07
```

and the current date: 2013-09-03 so i try this:

```
$dates = unserialize($row['dates']);
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");

$array = array($dates);
if (in_array($currentDate, $array)) {
echo "IS HERE !";
}
```

but with out luck.

Comment: `var_dump($array)`  and make sure this var. is an array with the dates as values.

Comment: Are you sure your array looks the way you want it? What about `in_array($currentDate, $dates)`?

Comment: What is `$row['dates']`? `array()` isn't a method and doesn't magically convert a string into an array.

Comment: When i insert in mysql row['dates'] it's like this $array_dates=mysql_escape_string(serialize($dates));

Comment: @TimDinh after i do this: "array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(54) "2013-09-03,2013-09-04,2013-09-06,2013-09-05,2013-09-07"
}"

Comment: @RobertCoroianu Ah ok then I added the answer! Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said `var_dump($row["dates"])` results in:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(54) "2013-09-03,2013-09-04,2013-09-06,2013-09-05,2013-09-07" }
```

Meaning `$row["dates"][0]` contains your string with all dates.

You can do this to test:"

```
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");

$date_array = explode(',', $row["dates"][0]); // Create an array with all your dates

if (in_array($currentDate, $date_array)) {
    echo "IS HERE !";
}
```

You can also do this:

```
// Because $row["dates"][0] is a string with dates, you can simply search the date as string.
if(strpos($row["dates"][0], $currentDate) !== FALSE){
    echo "IS HERE !";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

How about getting only the rows with today's date ?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(myDate) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: He wants to know if within his mysql results an entry exists with the current date. The question clearly doesn't say he wants only results from today. Please leave these kinds of *suggestions* within the comments.

Comment: Perhaps he didn't know that he could just pull the records straight from the database. In which case we should let him/her know that is more efficient instead of running a loop with and trying to pick the rows he wants.It's not bad to think 1 step ahead rather than just replying.

Comment: Your keyword "perhaps" is right. This is up for discussion,NOT a definitive answer. That's why you should've discussed this in the comment section. Don't just simply throw answers at it. It's not thinking 1 step ahead, it's a small chance on correct answer and a big chance of S.O. pollution, until discussed with OP. Less karmagunning, and better answers makes S.O. a better place.

Comment: I want to search in one column like "2013-09-24, 2013-09-06" if is exist current date. @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas

Comment: You want to search 1 column in your table and see if there are any records with today's date? In that case what is your date column name?